# the difference between SF and an accent mark

Tags: dynamics, articulation

what is the difference between these two? I know Sf is a dynamic, but what if it is already in a forte section?

and with sf do you play every note following as sf until another dynamic change or do you go back to the prior dynamic automatically?

Comment: Just to clarify: There's a misconception in the duplicate question that's affecting you as well. Unless perhaps there are a few rare exceptions that I don't know about, "*sf*" doesn't "start a forte passage." It only ever affects one single note. It's unlike, say "*fp*", after which one continues *piano*. In other words, I would not actually call *sf* "a dynamic," but rather an expression marking.

Comment: Hm... I'm starting to sense the need for something not covered in the proposed duplicate, a question for "What's the difference between *sf*, *sfz*, *fz*, and an accent?" (With the answer being "little that we can maintain dogmatically; only whatever difference we can document the composer intending; the first three can largely be regarded as variations on the same word across time and region, unless a given composer distinguishes among them; plus, all of them are going to come out sounding pretty similar.")

Answer (score 1):

The accent is an articulation, with implications about how hard you attack the note.  sf is a sudden change of dynamic for one note.    In practice, it would be interesting to get a musician to  play both and ask a panel of experts to vote which was which!

Answer (score 1):

This can be the source of considerable confusion because ***sf*** is the abbreviation for two different things.

> ***sf = sfz*** = *sforzando/sforzato*
>
> ***sf*** = subito forte

*Subito forte* is a (sudden) change in dynamics to *forte*

---

> *sf* / subito forte / suddenly loud
>
> *sfz* / sfortzando / sudden accent
>
> [Matti Carter; *Pianist's Handbook*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pianist_s_Handbook/Jl9-DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22sf%20subito%20forte%22&pg=PA175&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

This is misleading, because it fails to show that *sf* can be also be used for *sfz*.

---

Schumann uses mostly *sf* in his piano music, but he sometimes uses *sfz* in the same score—and even in the same passage:

[image]

*Novelletten*, Op.21 n.1 (Henle)

(The *sfz* was apparently restored in the Henle urtext; I  see *sf* in some early editions, including that by Clara Schumann.)

Comment: Your answer here also answers the proposed duplicate, [Does Sforzando really mean a stronger accent?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/89992/does-sforzando-really-mean-a-stronger-accent), very well.

Comment: Intriguing. I see that the Carter source says "subito forte" plain as day, but I've never encountered such a usage, only ones where a one-note effect is intended. For subito forte, I usually see "*sub. f*", or fully spelled out. I wonder whether there are many examples of "sf" for subito? I would imagine they might be limited to certain composers or perhaps are counter-practices by less-informed sources...

Comment: @AndyBonner If you google around, you'll see a bit of bulletin-board discussion about *sf* as *subito forte*.  (Schumann has other more elaborate combos with *sf* that are often hard to fathom.) You can make a case that, unless there is a *cresc.* or *decrecs.* before it, any *f* after a different level of sound would start *subito*, i.e. coming after a *p* or even *ff* passage.